# squares showing upon implicit conversion from numeric to char

Tags: arrays, octave

I am trying to test the behavior of adding number in an array containing a string using the following code :

```
warning: implicit conversion from numeric to char
```

I do understand the error and all, but the weird thing is that I get squares for the numbers, as in the image[image: code and error] and I don't understand what these are

Comment: From [the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Concatenating-Strings.html#Concatenating-Strings): "All string concatenation functions except cstrcat convert numerical input into character data by **taking the corresponding ASCII character for each element**." The squares are how your font renders characters that aren't in its table.

Comment: ascii(3) and ascii(5) are certainly in Octave's table, but are not printable. They are represented by these squares.

Comment: Octave doesn’t have lists. Everything is an array. For heterogeneous data, use the cell array, which is an array of arrays, each element in the cell array is an array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you, I edited the question to an array. Its what I actually meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mix heterogeneous input data in an array with Octave, you must use a cell array as container, that is, use braces instead of brackets to "concatenate" data:

```
>> a6 = {"test", 3, 5}
a6 =
{
  [1,1] = test
  [1,2] = 3
  [1,3] = 5
}
```

Otherwise, as commented by Raymond Chen, Octave tries to convert some data to make homogeneous (of the same type) all of them.